# Flot with jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a plot that I'm creating everything is working good except when i click the button it generates the lines for my data. If I hit the button again it just writes over the first ajax request instead of starting over from scratch, which is what I want. Please help This is my ajax call.

```
 $('#process').click(function(e) {

    var market = '&market=' + $('#market').val();
    var productgroup = '&productgroup=' + $('#curve').val();
    var from = '&from=' + $('#date_from').val();
    var to = '&to=' + $('#date_to').val();
    var lookback = '&lookback=' + $('.timeframe').attr('id');
    var fullUrl = url + market + productgroup + from + to + lookback;
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url: fullUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onDataReceived,
            error: onError//,
            // data: data
        });

});
```

Here's options for my plot

```
  var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: .1
        },
        points: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: [1, "day"],
        timeformat: "%m/%d/%Y",
        panRange: timespan
    },
    yaxis: {
        mode: "money",
        tickDecimals: 2,
        panRange: [0, 100],
        tickFormatter: dollarFormatter
    },
    zoom: {
        interactive: true
    },
    pan: {
        interactive: true
    }
};
```

And here's the function to create the plot

```
var data = [];

$.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
```

And this is my onDataReceived function

```
 function onDataReceived(series) {

    // Push the new data onto our existing data array
    var count = 0;
    for(var prop in series) {
        if(series.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            ++count;
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if (!alreadyFetched[series[i].label]) {

            data.push(series[i]);
        }
    }

    $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
}
```

Comment: Your question need more details,which library you use to plot,where is function that plot and what arguements it takes ....

Comment: The library that I'm using is called flot.

Comment: Can you post your onDataReceived function?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods

As per the API, you might want to use setData() and draw() to redraw

```
var data = [];
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
```

then in onDataRecieved

```
plot.setData(data);
plot.draw();
```

instead of recreating the flot on the placeholder

Comment: I tried using that and it still didn't work. It will draw that the legend over and over again vertically down the plot.